# How to convert Unix timestamp to hhmmss?

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

How to convert Unix timestamp (ie. 1286374738) to hhmmss?

Comment: google -> php unix timestamp to time -> http://php.net/date Not a rocket science, eh?

Answer (score 5):

```
date('His', $timestamp);
```

where $timestamp contains the unix timestamp , H = 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros , can use h = 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros ; i = Minutes with leading zeros , s = Seconds, with leading zeros

Comment: I didn't try to see how it turned out, but `e` & `r` are also valid format characters (timezone identifier & RFC 2822 formatted date - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). So, how about `date('Her', $timestamp);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the many converter sites:
http://convert-unix-time.com
http://www.epoch-converter.com

... they also have converting examples for many programming languages.

Comment: Although not specified in the title or question text, the `php` tag on this question indicates that the asker wants to do this programatically with PHP. Your answer isn't really sufficiently specific here, so I've downvoted. Entirely forgivable that you'd miss the tag, though, since you're new.

Comment: +1 for you, but I upvoted him, because 1) he's new & needs encouragement and 2) he did say `they also have converting examples for many programming languages`