# Convert unix timestamp

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Unix timestamp to hhmmss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578204/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-hhmmss)

Here is unix timestamp of today

```
1306702800
```

How to convert it to look like  30-05-2011 using php ?

Comment: [RTFM](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Look, there is documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: and a lot of similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+convert+unix+timestamp

Comment: @bazmegakapa Yeah, that helps if you don't know what to look for. Especially when you look at the great naming applied here. Call `time()` to get the current date/time. Then call `date()` to convert that time to string. Still confused me sometimes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: @GolezTrol Whichever you find in the manual, the `See Also` section is a good start. This is the type of question that seems to show no effort. I wouldn't say I was born already possessing this knowledge, but if you start reading the manual, you will find it even without looking for it. And I don't want to hurt the OP or anyone, I mean to give help through my criticism.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert (and arbitrarily re-format) timestamps as such:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', 1306702800);
```

Additionally, you can get the current timestamp via the [time](http://www.php.net/time) function, so you could output the current date via: `echo date('d-m-Y', time());`.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's date functions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

See [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date('d-m-Y', '%your-time-stamp%');
```