# How to check hours in timestamp is in between a particular range of hours?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Unix timestamp to hhmmss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578204/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-hhmmss)

I have a timestamp in the format of:

```
1330559989
```

How to check the hours in the timestamp is in between 6 hours and 23 hours?

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date('H', 1330559989)` will give you the hours in 24h format with a leading zero, in this example: `23`.

There is also a specific function for the hour of a timestamp called [`getdate`](http://php.net/getdate) which offers an array interface to that information ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fo3S1o)):

```
getdate(1330559989)['hours']; # 23
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$hrs=date('H', 1330559989);
if ($hrs>= 6 && $hrs<= 23) {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the time between now and that given timestamp, then you can use:

```
<?php
    echo date("H", strtotime(now)-1330559989); // Displays the difference from now.
    echo date("H", 1330559989); // Displays that time!
?>
```

Hope this helps! :)