# Convert Date(*) number to time (d/m/Y) in php

Tags: php

simple question, I have a date, I think it a Timestamp, I'm not sure but it looks something like that:

```
'/Date(1403024400000)/'
```

How do I convert that to  `D/M/Y` Just a regular Europe date.

Comment: `function foo($arg) { if ($arg == 1403024400000) return "*/*/2014..";  }`

Comment: [convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213528/convert-timestamp-to-readable-date-time-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578204/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-hhmmss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to extract the timestamp from the string first. This can be done using a regex.

The timestamp is a UNIX timestamp with millisecond accuracy. Therefore you need to remove the last 3 digits from it before you can convert it to the desired format.

Like this:

```
$string = '/Date(1403024400000)/';

// retrieve the timestamp with a regex    
preg_match('/Date\((.*?)\)/', $string, $matches);
$timestamp = $matches[1];

// the timestamp contains milliseconds. remove the last 3 digits
$timestamp = substr($timestamp, 0, -3);

// convert to d/m/Y using date()
echo date('d/m/Y', $timestamp);
~
```

Output:

```
17/06/2014
```

Btw, there is no "regular" European date format. In germany for example we are using `d.m.Y` (using dots as separator)

Answer (score 0):

Chop off the last three numbers (as it doesn't seem you care about that anyway) and do something like this

```
echo date('d/m/Y', 1403024400);
```